# GUI programming/arrays in Python

Tags: python

I need a little more elaboration on arrays in GUI programming. For image processing, I was given the following piece of code as an example of image processing:

```
def grayscale(im):
    height=len(im)
    width = len(im[0])
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            average = sum(im[row][col])/3
            im[row][col]=[average,average,average]
    return im
```

The final line before the code returns--what does it mean? The code is supposed to be running through pixel by pixel and averaging out the RGB values to get a grayscale value--how is the sum of each pixel/3 the average? How does the code know what the red, blue, and green values are?

Answer (score 1):

Each color in a pixel is defined by a variation of three components : Red, green and blue, generally oscillating between 0 and 255, creating 16 millions colors (`255^3`).

A shade of gray is represented by three identical values for red, green and blue.

There are several methods to achieve a grayscale convertion, including the quick n' dirty average method (see others [here](http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/)).

Since grayscale only needs one scale (from white to black), you can just average the three components with the formula `(R + G + B) / 3` to make a new color with this value for each color component, thus creating a gray shade.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume for this answer that `im` is a 3D list containing `[R, G, B]` values for each pixel in an image, or, in other words, that it's of the form:

```
im = [ [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]],
       [[g, h, i], [j, k, l]] ]
```

Let's handle your questions one by one:

First, you asked how the sum of each pixel, divided by three, is the average. To answer that, let's look at the definition of the average (more precisely, of the arithmetic mean) of a list of numbers, which is "the sum of the numbers in the list, divided by the number of elements in the list."
In math symbols, it looks like this, where `a` is the name of the list, and `n` is its length:
[image: formula]
So, the average of a list of that is 3 items long is:
[image: formula]
Now, in this case, we're storing the value of each pixel as a list containing data of the form `[R, G, B]`. According to the formula we just described, the average of the three values is equal to their sum, divided by their length. If we apply that formula, we get:

[image: formula]

Now for your second question, how the code knows what the red, green, and blue values are. The answer is that it knows those values because we tell it where to look. When we started, we defined `im` as a 3D list, containing `[R, G, B]` values for each pixel. Whoever wrote the code decided that the best way to represent that data would be through a list like that, and so they wrote all the rest of their code in a way that relied on that representation. Now, based on the code you provided, we can't actually guarantee that the values are `[R, G, B]`. They could be `[G, R, B]`, or `[B, G, R]`. However, standard practice when dealing with colors is to order them as `[R, G, B]`, and, unless you see a specific reason to think otherwise, that should be your assumption. Also, for this particular code, it doesn't matter what order the values are, because the average of `[10, 20, 30]` is the same as the average of `[20, 30, 10]` or any other rearrangement of those values.

Finally, let's talk about how finding the average of the `[R, G, B]` values converts the image to grayscale. A neutral color is defined as any color for which R, G, and B are all equal. White is a neutral color (R = G = B = 100%), as is black (R = G = B = 0%). The same is true for all shades in between white and black. In other words, any color where R = G = B will be white, black, or some shade of gray.

So, to convert to grayscale, we just need to map a given pixel to a corresponding pixel where R = G = B. One of the easiest ways to make R, G, and B equal is to set:
[image: formula]

And that's exactly what the code here is doing.